# Open_Workbook Routine Works Manually but not Automatically

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have the below code pasted into the ThisWorkbook object. However everytime I open the workbook it does nothing, as soon as I go into VBA and manually step through it, it works and the combobox get populated? I'm sure its a setting or something simple rather than anything complicated with the code but I'm all out of ideas as to why this is failing.

Any help would be much appreciated

```
Option Explicit
Public bClear As Boolean

Private Sub Open_Workbook()

With Application
    .Calculation = xlManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim stSQL As String, rst As ADODB.Recordset, k As Integer, vaData As Variant
Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim ConnectionString As String
ConnectionString = "Provider=sqloledb.1;data source=SQL-SERVER;Initial catalog=SQL-DB;Integrated Security = SSPI;"
Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

stSQL = "EXEC('SELECT NAME FROM TABLE1')"

With objConn
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open ConnectionString
    Set rst = .Execute(stSQL)
End With

With rst
    Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing
    k = .Fields.Count
    vaData = .GetRows
End With

Sheets("Menu").CB_Book.List = Application.Transpose(vaData)

objConn.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing

bClear = True

With Application
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: macros enabled by default?

Comment: I have Enable all controls ticked in my activeX settings and enable all macros in my macro settings. I also have trust access to the VBA project ticked too.

Comment: What about references? I have 8 standard ones ticked.

Comment: Have you tried using the Call Function? Remove the code from the Workbook_Open and put it in a seperate Private Sub, then Call NewPrivateSub from within the Workbook_Open

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
Private Sub Open_Workbook()
```

To this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
```

Comment: Thank you! Man I hate VBA sometimes!